# PHPUNIT running on selenium server

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get an array of elements using xpath and load the results into an array and then perform `assertCount()`. Here is the code I that I have. I am new to this and I am not sure why elementList is empty?

```
<?php

require_once('Base.php');

class FollowupTest extends Test_Base {

    protected $session = null;

    /**
    * Asserts that the count of list elements on the page is equal
    * to three utilizing an xpath expression.
    */
    public function testCountListElements() {
        $elementsList = $this->session->elements('xpath', '//li');
        $this->assertCount(3, sizeof($elementList));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? What Selenium Server are you using? Are you using a library (like PHPUnit_Selenium extension) for Selenium API? What is Test_Base? Is it a custom class from you?

Comment: I am using selenium server 2.25.0 (Webdriver). Test_Base is a class in phpunit. It is not custom. $elementList should be an array and I need to load it with the elements retrieved  from $this->session->elements('xpath', '//li')

Comment: Well, I'm no expert, but I think you should be extending Selenium2TestCase. session() is available on that class. I think the manual should provide a good start: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you extend PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase, you can count elements with this [structure](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php#L92):

```
$elements = $this->elements($this->using('xpath')->value('//li'));
$this->assertEquals(3, count($elements));
```